# What things can i use to make it a scrambed egg while still in the shell

Tags: food, eggs

I really want to know please? Scrambled eggs are delicious and tasty, I want to eat hard boiled egg too! What can it be taste like if I add the two?  Iwant to learn

Comment: This question isn't about a problem, making it off-topic here. I'm going to have to close this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy (via [Wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Scrambled-Eggs-Inside-the-Shell)):

Put the egg in the sleeve of a long-arm shirt, secure it with rubber bands, wind up, pull to unwind, repat until egg is scrambled (shine a flashlight through the egg — if it produces an orange hue, it's fully scrambled.). (See link for details, including images).

As additional service: you might want to have a look into [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Search-Google), as your question is easily found via a simple web search using the exact question you asked here.

*Edit: added way to know when finished from original source as suggested in comment*